# Magento 2 : How to check if we are on a category page or product page?

Tags: magento2, category

Is there a way I can check that If a user on a category page,or an individual product page in Magento 2?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean after  a random user login we should come to know the user is on which page.

Comment: It's not required for user to login. I just want to check the page is category page or product page. Like in Magento 1 We can check it like this:
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can try below code it might help you.

**Inject an instance** of `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` in your **class constructor.**

If you are in a controller you don't need to do it. You can already access it like this `$request = $this->getRequest()`

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    ...
    $this->_request = $request;
}
```

Then you can check if is **category or product** like this:

```
if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
    //you are on the product page
}
if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
    //you are on the category page
}
```

Comment: If you directly want it in phtml file then use like this - $this->getRequest()->getFullActionName()  here is the if condition I used : if($this->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view'){...}

Comment: Hi @Arjun, How would you then get the name of the category you're in?

Comment: how to check this using jquery? @Arun

Answer (score 12):

I guess, we can directly use

```
$this->getRequest()->getFullActionName()
```

in .phtml file to get current page action.

Comment: perfect answer!!! made my day :) +1

Answer (score 9):

You can use instance of \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http in your class constructor. If you are in a controller you don't need to do it.

You can already access it like this `$request = $this->getRequest()`

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    ...
    $this->_request = $request;
}
```

Then you can check if is homepage or categorypage or productpage like this:

```
if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
    //you are on the homepage
}
if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
    //you are on the product page
}
if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
    //you are on the category page
}
```

Otherwise directly use in phtml file using object manager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
```

Comment: Have you try above code ?

Comment: how to check this using jquery?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a template file i.e. .phtml then directly you can call on the page using below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$request = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');

if ($request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
//you are on the homepage
}

if ($request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
//you are on the product page
}

if ($request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
//you are on the category page
}
```

and if you to get a current category and its data you can do it via

```
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');

$category->getData('schbang_category_name');
```

where `schbang_category_name` is my custom category attribute

I hope this might help someone.

Answer (score -2):

you can add conditional, such as

```
if($this->getProductPage()) {
  //this is a product page, do some stuff
}
elseif($this->getCategoryPage()) {
  //this is a category page, do some stuff
}
```

Comment: There is no function `getCategoryPage` anywhere in Magento 2, at least not in 2.1.10